# Sublime Text 3 - Prettier / jsPrettier error: parser.parse is not a function

Tags: sublimetext3, prettier, jsprettier

In Sublime Text 3, I'm attempting to use jsPrettier (which worked fine previously) and getting this error in the console:
`TypeError: parser.parse is not a function`. I've tried reinstalling prettier (globally) and jsPrettier (ST3 package) several times, as well as restarting Sublime. How do I get prettier working again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pathing issue. Somehow Sublime lost the path to prettier. Getting that path (from `which prettier`) and adding it as `prettier_cli_path` to `JsPrettier.sublime-settings` (from Preferences -> Package Settings -> JsPrettier -> Settings - User) fixes the issue.

```
{
    "prettier_cli_path": "~/path/to/prettier"
}
```